# C# Marshalling unsigned char* array from C++ DLL (in and out)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am having trouble marshalling data between a C# application and an existing C++ DLL.  The caveats that are making this difficult are that it is an unsigned char pointer to an array, and I need access to the data (from all fields) after the call in C#.  I would like to avoid using unsafe code, if at all possible.

Here is the C++ signature:

```
BYTE GetData(unsigned char *Data_Type, unsigned char *Data_Content, unsigned int *Data_Length);
```

I've tried a bunch of things in C#, but here's what I have now:

```
[DllImport("somecpp.dll")]
public static extern byte GetData([In][Out] ref byte Data_Type, [In][Out] ref byte[] Data_Content, [In][Out] ref int Data_Length);
```

Then calling it, I am attempting this:

```
byte retrievedData = GetData(ref data_type, ref data_content, ref data_length);
```

This is definitely not working, and I'm not sure what to try next.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `uint` would be the correct type for Data_Length, but I don't know why that would cause this problem. As always when talking about things not working, please be specific, are you receiving an error message if so what is the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ref byte[]` parameter matches `unsigned char**`. That's one level of indirection too many.

The p/invoke should be

```
[DllImport("somecpp.dll")]
public static extern byte GetData(
    ref byte Data_Type,
    [In,Out] byte[] Data_Content,
    ref uint Data_Length
);
```

It is plausible that the function uses cdecl. We can't tell that from here.

I also suspect that the `Data_Type` argument should be `out` rather than `ref`.