# What is the c# dll import declaration of the following

Tags: c#, c++, vb6, dllimport

I have the following function from a c++ header file:

```
__int16 __stdcall s_em4305_login (HANDLE m_hUSB, int DataRate, UCHAR * password);
```

When I run the VB equavelent:

```
Private Declare Function RF_EM4305_Login Lib "SRF32.dll" Alias "s_em4305_login" (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal DataRate As Long, ByRef bytes As Byte) As Integer
```

I get -1100 back as a value

When I run the c# equavilent:

```
[DllImport("SRF32.dll", EntryPoint = "s_em4305_login")]
private static extern ushort RF_EM4305_Login(IntPtr handle, int DataRate,byte[] password);
```

I get a different value. The 3rd paramater is most likely declared incorrectly. Can someone please assist in converting the c++ declaration to c#

**Update**

I have added some additional declarations

private static extern ushort RF_EM4305_Login(IntPtr handle, int DataRate,IntPtr password);
private static extern ushort RF_EM4305_Login(IntPtr handle, int DataRate,ref byte[] password);

With all 3 c# declarations I get the value "64436" returned.

Comment: Return type should be `System.Int16` aka `Short`.  `Integer` was 16 bit back in Classic VB, but not in VB.NET.  Similarly, second parameter should be `System.Int32` aka `Integer`.  `Long` was 32 bits in Classic VB, but that too changed in VB.NET.  And the first parameter has problems, and should use `System.IntPtr` as does the C# declaration. 
 Different results between VB.NET and C# do not imply your C# declaration is in error... on the contrary it appears the C# declaration is correct and the VB.NET call is erroneous.

Comment: As general advice, never use the language keyword for types in p/invoke declarations.  Instead, use the names of the types in the `System` namespace, which explicitly describe the size.

Comment: @jwdonahue: Probably `string` along with `CharSet.Ansi` would be easier to use, but `byte[]` is not incorrect.

Comment: No I think I had a brain fart.  I suspect string is not a simple type, but I haven't looked at C# code in over a year.  `ref byte[] password' might be better?

Comment: Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit DLL? Ironacally, it uses __int16 for the return value, but then it uses int in DataRate parameter. We have to know how many bytes is the int.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097528/c-sharp-marshalling-unsigned-char-array-from-c-dll-in-and-out

Comment: Try `System.Int16` (or `short`) instead of `ushort` for the return type in C#.  I thought you meant the return value was actually different, not just the same bit pattern treated unsigned...

Comment: @felix-b: All C++ compilers made for Windows platforms that can run C# code use 32-bit `int` and 32-bit `long`.

Comment: @BenVoigt my bad, you're right

Comment: There is almost no degree of equivalence between your VB and C# versions.  It's as if no effort was made at all.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: I suspect the VB version may have been copy+pasted from documentation old enough to use the Classic VB rules and not VB.NET, but OP didn't know enough to not use the [tag:vb.net] tag

Comment: Its old VB not VB.Net

Comment: @BenVoigt: In no possible VB world does a VB Integer convert to a C# ushort and a VB Byte convert to a C# array of byte.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: You show your unfamiliarity with Classic VB.  There were no unsigned types, so you picked the signed type of the correct size.  And passing the first element ByRef was the correct way to pass a pointer to the entire array.

Comment: @Eminem: Then why have you said `vb.net` in the question?

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are obviously right about the lack of unsigned types in classic VB, but classic VB certainly did have array parameters and they looked an awful lot like VB.NET array parameters - e.g., "myArray() As Long".

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: And when used in DLL access, they become SAFEARRAY, not an ordinary pointer.  To pass an ordinary pointer, ByRef the first element is the correct way in VB Classic

Comment: @BenVoigt aplogies. Corrected my tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your unmanged code treats the `password` as a Null-terminated ansi string, this two should both work.

```
[DllImport("SRF32.dll", EntryPoint = "s_em4305_login", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern short RF_EM4305_Login(IntPtr handle, int DataRate, string password);

[DllImport("SRF32.dll", EntryPoint = "s_em4305_login")]
private static extern short RF_EM4305_Login(IntPtr handle, int DataRate, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string password);
```

And your C# declaration wasn't wrong either, because ushort 64436 equers short -1100 in memory.

Comment: It's absolutely certain that neither of these will return a negative result, which appears to be the main thing OP is concerned with.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, I was focused on the 3rd paramter part. I will update my answer.

Comment: Wow! I completely forgot about ushort and short! Thanks. Will mark this as the answer